# write a file in php

Tags: php

This function fetches the records from the db. Now I want it to write them to a file. Please help me.

```
function selectcsv($classname)
    {
        echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblstuden WHERE classname = $classname;"; 
        $obj_db = new DB();
        $obj_db->query($sql);

        while($row = $obj_db->rsset()){
        $this->_id($row[id]);
        $this->_studentname($row[studentname]);
        $this->_rollnumber($row[rollnumber]);
        $this->_classname($row[classname]);

        $out = $out . $row[studentname] . " , ". $row[rollnumber] . "\n";
        }

        $obj_db->db_close();
```

The above portion is running

```
$myFile = "write.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "write::";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = $_POST[read];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: the code create a file write.txt but it doesnt have any data in it.

Comment: i want my data which is viewed to me . shall be write in a file.

Comment: Shouldn't this `$_POST[read];` be `$_POST['read'];`?

Answer (score 0):

here try this one,

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition:attachment; filename=".$myFile);

echo $out;
```

In your Case:

```
$myFile = "write.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $out;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = $_POST['read'];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: OP is trying to write to a file, not to a header.

Comment: oh, i see, sorry for that. well this code writes the file but to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You never write your `$out` data to the file.

Instead of:

```
$stringData = "write::";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = $_POST[read];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

You should:

```
fwrite($fh, $out);
```

You should try to read and understand the [PHP manual page for fwrite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

Comment: Remember that when you get useful answers to your questions, that you should **accept** an answer to thank the people who answer the question. You should do this for all your questions, not just this one.

Comment: Look for the check mark next to an answer, under the number of votes. You may also look at this page for more information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/172778

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter to the method and then use output buffering to create the content to store in your file, as `ob_clean();` is used it wont get outputted but you will still have your `$out` incase you wanted to return from the method:

```
<?php 
function selectcsv($classname,$writeFile=true)
{
    echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblstuden WHERE classname = $classname;";
    $obj_db = new DB();
    $obj_db->query($sql);

    if($writeFile==true){ob_start();}

    while($row = $obj_db->rsset()){
        $this->_id($row['id']);
        $this->_studentname($row['studentname']);
        $this->_rollnumber($row['rollnumber']);
        $this->_classname($row['classname']);
        if($writeFile==true){
            echo $row['studentname'] . " , ". $row['rollnumber'] . PHP_EOL;
        }
        $out .= $row['studentname'] . " , ". $row['rollnumber'] . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if($writeFile==true){
       $tofile = ob_get_contents();
       ob_clean();
       file_put_contents($classname.'.csv',$tofile);
    }

    return $out;
    $obj_db->db_close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myFile = "write.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

$stringData = "write::";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

$stringData = $_POST['read'];
if(isempty($stringData){echo 'Nothing to write';}
else
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

fclose($fh);
```

I think  the array index strings should be enclodes in quotes, and also, you can check of POST array contains valid data  or not